# JavaScript: confusion about WeakSet and its effects on garbage collection

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list

I have been grinding leetcode and I encountered this question https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/ where it asks you to find the intersection of two LinkedList. One solution (not the best one I know) is to use a hash set to keep track of the first linked list while traversing through it and then traversing through the second list. When we found out that there is a duplicate node then that is the intersection.

For example, `E` is the intersection

```
A -> B
       \
         E -> F       
       /    
C -> D
```

The way I solved it is to use a `WeakSet` as the hash set to store the reference of the first linked list.

Here is the code

```js
var getIntersectionNode = function(headA, headB) {
    let hashSet = new WeakSet()

    while(headA){
        hashSet.add(headA)
        headA = headA.next
    }
    while(headB){
        if(hashSet.has(headB)) return headB
        headB = headB.next
    }
    return null
};
```

My question is, since `WeakSet` has this nice feature - when no other references to an object stored in the WeakSet exist, those objects can be garbage collected. If we go back to the example here, when we are iterating through `A -> B -> E -> F`, we are adding every node into  the hash set, but we don't preserve the reference for every node, i.e. `headA = headA.next`. So that means after I added one node into the hash set and I advanced to the next node, the reference to the previous node is gone, then it should be garbage collected from the hash set right? Then how come the solution would pass?

For example, when we are at `A`, we store the `A` into the hash set, and we advance to `B`, now there is no way to reference back to `A`, with `WeakSet` it should have been garbage collected. But clearly if that is the case the solution wouldn't work. Can someone point out where my understanding is wrong here?

Comment: "*then it should be garbage collected from the hash set right? Then how come the solution would pass?*" why do you believe the code that provides you with the linked lists and then checks your solution doesn't itself keep a reference to the linked lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues here:

- The original objects passed into `getIntersectionNode` from the caller will still exist *at least* until the function finishes. If you do

  ```
  someFn({ foo: 'bar' })
  ```

  The object won't get garbage collected until synchronous JS processing has finished; the GC only runs once JS is idle, and even then, it'll often take a few seconds. If you add an element to a WeakSet, and you were *somehow* able to observe when exactly it gets removed from it due to there no longer being any references to it, it would take some time.
- Even then, even if unreferenceable objects were GC'd immediately, in this case, all that's needed is for the *one* intersection node to remain referenceable. If there's an intersection, that intersection node will be a child of `headA` somewhere, and that node will also exist somewhere nested inside `headB`; a reference still exists to it inside `headB` even after iterating through `headA`.

Unless your script carries out asynchronous tasks (like wait for user input, or a `setTimeout`), there's no benefit to using a WeakSet over a Set (or a WeakMap over a Map), since the garbage collector won't run in time for it to be of any use.

Comment: I see. thanks for the reply. Does that mean there is no need to prefer `WeakSet` over `Set` in this particular case? I tested both and leetcode said there seems no difference in terms of memory usage? I wonder even if I use `Set` in the function, once the function returns and there is no closure that closes over the local variables of that function, `Set` would be garbage collected regardless since itself is no longer accessible once the function returns, so there is really no need to use `WeakSet` here?

Comment: Indeed - since nothing here is asynchronous, might as well use a plain Set.

Comment: ok. Just wanted to double check if my understanding is right here: so if we have a function `function foo() {const set = new Set(); set.add({a: 'a'})}` and once we run the function `foo`, since there is no way to access `set` again, it and the object we added in it will all be garbage collected right, even we are not using a `WeakSet`?

Comment: Yes, that set'll get GC'd.